# SQL Server Count field values without merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

How do I create a COUNT column to count the repetitive values?

And I want to keep the table EXACTLY as below but add the last column (count_id).

[image]

The values at the left come from a JOIN so they are "equal".

Thanks! (I tried a lot)

Answer (score 1):

You just want `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by id, name, department) as count_id
from t;
```